# How to create multiple URLs for JIRA and Confluence?

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, jira, confluence

Task:

- We have a several DNS aliases (ex. project1.domain.com, project2.domain.com)
- DNS aliases connected to JIRA Server by IP
- Need link, ex. from project1.domain.com to jira.domain.com/project/TEST1
- Need link, ex, from project2.domain.com to jira.domain.com/project/TEST2

How next? any ideas?

Thank you for the Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your webserver, you need as many *Virtual Hosts* as domains you have declared, and each *Virtual Host* will have one *HTTP redirection*.

For example :

```
 VirtualHost project1.domain.com
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule   ^/+(.*)$  http://jira.domain.com/project/TEST1 [R]
```

Comment: This is need install, forex, nginx web-server on VM with JIRA server.  Tomcat9 from JIRA server for not eq?

Comment: I am talking about Apache as it is the tag you choose. But you can use the same idea with nginx or even Tomcat although more difficult to configure for this one.